# Get title and URL of last 5 websites in history

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to include a small window that shows the last 5 pages they visited on a my site.

Primarily I'd like it to show the title of the page and the URL so I can link them to it. It would be great if I can filter these to a word or website since I'd like to be for my site only.

Would **JavaScript** be good for this and does it work cross browsers?

Comment: Do you mean on your site, or any site?

Comment: I'd prefer it was on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only look 1 page back which is document.referrer but I am not sure how to get the title.

If you are monitoring your own site you can use localStorage to store the last 5 pages but if you want to monitor other sites then no you cant do it in Javascript that will be a privacy concern if you can do it.

localStorage is HTML5 but its already supported by major browsers.

Comment: Yes, it'll be on my site only. localStorage sounds like a good idea to start. What can I store?

Comment: [link](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/storage.html) Read about it here. It has good info regarding localStorage and checking if the browser supports it. you can store anything in localStorage but remember that it saves it as text. So you cant save objects but there's no stopping you from storing object as JSON then parse the JSON back to object when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing server-side scripting it should be fairly simple to keep a record of what page they have visited on your website. It could be done with Javascript and cookies, but it does not necessarily have to be done that way.

Comment: Doing it server side means having to be very careful with caching, otherwise a page request might be fetched locally or intercepted by an intervening proxy.

Comment: I was thinking of using PHP but I knew there were some draw backs.